# Benefit of using Func as argument in static method for thread safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing, async-await, thread-safety

Given the below C# code:

```
public class Info
{
    public string Status { get; set; } = "Init";
}

public static class InfoHelper
{
    public static async Task UpdateStatusV1(Func<Info> getInfo)
    {
        Info someInfo = getInfo();
        someInfo.Status = "Checking...";
        await Task.Delay(1000); // simulating complicated and important work
        someInfo.Status = "Updated";
    }

    public static async Task UpdateStatusV2(Info someInfo)
    {
        someInfo.Status = "Checking...";
        await Task.Delay(1000); // simulating complicated and important work
        someInfo.Status = "Updated";
    }
}

public static async Task UpdateStatusV3(Func<Info> getInfo)
{
    await DoComplicatedAndImportantWorkV1();

    async Task DoComplicatedAndImportantWorkV1()
    {
        Info someInfo = getInfo();
        await Task.Delay(1000); // simulating complicated and important work
        someInfo.Status = "Updated";
    }
}

public static async Task UpdateStatusV4(Info someInfo)
{
    await DoComplicatedAndImportantWorkV2();

    async Task DoComplicatedAndImportantWorkV2()
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000); // simulating complicated and important work
        someInfo.Status = "Updated";
    }
}
```

Does InfoHelper.UpdateStatusV1 have any advantage over InfoHelper.UpdateStatusV2 with respect to thread safety?

Does InfoHelper.UpdateStatusV1 "***someInfo***" object safer to use and modify than InfoHelper.UpdateStatusV2?

Does InfoHelper.UpdateStatusV3 have any advantage over InfoHelper.UpdateStatusV4 with respect to thread safety - for example maintaining the same "***someInfo***" "thread context" of the calling method?

Comment: Using a `Func<>` doesn't change anything with regard to threading, it's still just a function that gets called.

Comment: It would depend entirely on what `getInfo` actually does, and how `UpdatestatusV2` is actually called. Either one could reuse an object (making threading unsafe because state is shared); either one could create a new object (making threading safe because no state is shared). (All this is assuming anything unsafe happens in the first place; simple  assignment of references is atomic, so only interleaving would be a problem.)

Comment: 1. Absolutely no, 2. Absolutely no. But if you are only changing the string property then there is like 0 chance you will mess up. The worst case would be the label is displaying the wrong status due to race condition. that's all

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I have added a third and fourth example that is a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

No useful difference whatsoever. Times a func is more useful:

- the code needs to supply parameters that the caller won't know
- the code needs to be able to invoke it multiple times with different arguments
- the code needs to execute the callback at a different point in time - perhaps after an `await`

In this case: no useful difference compared to just passing in the value directly. And lots of ways to introduce errors.

Comment: I have just updated the question with a third and fourth example, to be a bit more complicated. Do your comments still hold?

Comment: @S.A. in the 3rd example, the delegate invoke happens *before* the first `await` (if we re-order the code so it compiles), so: nothing has changed. If it happened *after*, we'd then need to know: should we expect it to *matter* that we're executing it at a later time? is that relevant? if so: then yes, it might be useful. If not: then, no

Comment: Thank you. I was looking at legacy code that I need to update and modify (unfortunately cannot re-write); I needed to understand why a an argument had a Func with no input parameters passed as an argument to a static async extension method. The order of execution may vary... and I am not sure someInfo is threadsafe